# a puzzle game algorithm in as3

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, flash, puzzle

I am creating game like http://www.puzzlegames.org/814games-Connect-2-Game-game.html. so what should i add in `connected()` function? 
`fB` and `sB` are First and second button selected.
`fBN` and `sBN` are names of those buttons.
`allNull()` makes `fB`,`sB`, `fBN`, `sBN` null.

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
if (! another) {
    another = true;
    fB = e.target;
    fBN = e.target.name;
}
else {
    sB = e.target;
    sBN = e.target.name;
    if (fBN == sBN)
    {
        allNull();
    }
    else if (connected())
    {
        fB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onClick);
        sB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onClick);
        fB.alpha = 0;
        sB.alpha = 0;
        pairCount++;
        allNull();
        if (pairCount == 25)
        {
            gameOver = false;
            showScore();
            endGame();
        }
    }
    another = false;
}
```

}

Please help. I am trying to solve this problem since 15 days.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information do you have a dual indexed array with the entire map of buttons based on position, my assumption is you want to check in connected if the index of the button is only one off in any direction (top bottom left right).

Comment: Please try to explain better your problem.

Comment: I don't see the point of keeping the fB and the fBN ... If you keep fB you can just compare on that var, or even get the name fB.name! First look is looking ok, but you better post some further code / information ...

Comment: if u are able to solve this problem, mail me at justrockon0@googlemail.com i will give u details.